# Showing Warning and Can't get Roster

Tags: android, facebook, xmpp, asmack

I have used asmack-android-17-0.8.3.jar and using the following code.

```
 private void testLogin(){
        ConnectionConfiguration config = new ConnectionConfiguration("chat.facebook.com", 5222,"Smack");
        config.setSASLAuthenticationEnabled(true);
        config.setSecurityMode(ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.enabled);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
            config.setTruststoreType("AndroidCAStore");
            config.setTruststorePassword(null);
            config.setTruststorePath(null);
        } else {
            config.setTruststoreType("BKS");
            String path = System.getProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore");
            if (path == null)
                path = System.getProperty("java.home") + File.separator + "etc"
                    + File.separator + "security" + File.separator
                    + "cacerts.bks";
            config.setTruststorePath(path);
        }
        XMPPConnection xmpp = new XMPPConnection(config);
        SASLAuthentication.registerSASLMechanism("X-FACEBOOK-PLATFORM",SASLXFacebookPlatformMechanism.class);
        SASLAuthentication.supportSASLMechanism("X-FACEBOOK-PLATFORM", 0);

        Log.i("XMPPClient",
                "Access token to " + mFacebook.getAccessToken());
        Log.i("XMPPClient",
                "Access token to " + mFacebook.getAppId());
        Log.i("XMPPClient",
                "Access token to " + mFacebook.getAccessToken());
        try {
            xmpp.connect();
            Log.i("XMPPClient",
                    "Connected to " + xmpp.getHost());

        } catch (XMPPException e1) {
            Log.i("XMPPClient",
                    "Unable to " + xmpp.getHost());

            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            xmpp.login(APP_ID, mFacebook.getAccessToken());

            Log.i("XMPPClient",
                    " its logined ");

    //get roster
            Roster roster = xmpp.getRoster();
            Collection<RosterEntry> entries = roster.getEntries();
            System.out.println("Connected!");
            System.out.println("\n\n" + entries.size() + " buddy(ies):");
            for (RosterEntry entry : entries) {
                Log.i("test", entry.getName());
                Log.i("test", entry.getUser());
            }

          //send a chat message
            ChatManager chatmanager = xmpp.getChatManager();
            Chat newChat = chatmanager.createChat("koko.mgmg@chat.facebook.com", new MessageListener() {

                @Override
                public void processMessage(Chat chat, Message message) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                      Log.d("test", "message sent = "+ message);
                }
            });
            newChat.sendMessage("Cowdy!");

        } catch (XMPPException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

It is already complete login but there is warning show below and I can't get rosterlist and chat. I think the following warning make that can't get roster. How to slove this problem and how to get roster and chat? Please.

```
08-06 03:12:52.719: W/System.err(2573): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-06 03:12:52.759: W/System.err(2573):     at java.io.File.fixSlashes(File.java:185)
08-06 03:12:52.759: W/System.err(2573):     at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:134)
08-06 03:12:52.759: W/System.err(2573):     at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:105)
08-06 03:12:52.779: W/System.err(2573):     at org.jivesoftware.smack.ServerTrustManager.<init>(ServerTrustManager.java:71)
08-06 03:12:52.779: W/System.err(2573):     at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.proceedTLSReceived(XMPPConnection.java:871)
08-06 03:12:52.789: W/System.err(2573):     at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketReader.parsePackets(PacketReader.java:221)
08-06 03:12:52.789: W/System.err(2573):     at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketReader.access$000(PacketReader.java:44)
08-06 03:12:52.789: W/System.err(2573):     at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketReader$1.run(PacketReader.java:70)
```

Answer (score -1):

try this,may be it will work for u, i have same problem and in my case following solution works fine.

comment following code from your code and try again,

```
    config.setSecurityMode(ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.enabled);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
        config.setTruststoreType("AndroidCAStore");
        config.setTruststorePassword(null);
        config.setTruststorePath(null);
    } else {
        config.setTruststoreType("BKS");
        String path = System.getProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore");
        if (path == null)
            path = System.getProperty("java.home") + File.separator + "etc"
                + File.separator + "security" + File.separator
                + "cacerts.bks";
        config.setTruststorePath(path);
    }
```